# Do I need to complete Bleak Falls Barrow to buy land in Falkreath?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I haven't finished the Bleak Falls Barrow quest. But I have attempted repeatedly to purchase land in Falkreath. I am a Thane and there are no more quests available from the Steward or the Jarl. How do I buy land?

Comment: You need to have Hearthfire installed and then be above level 8 I believe to have received the letter inviting you to buy land.

Comment: If I remember correctly, the Jarl's quest if categorized as Miscellaneous.  Make use you kill his former "associates".  Falkreath is also mighty short on *visible* quests.  Pick veggies for the farmer in town & get paid.  Chop wood and sell it to the mill in town and the one on the lake shore north of town...

Comment: What are you talking about? You do Bleak Falls Barrow to get the Whiterun house, not the Falkreath house.

Answer (score 3):

To answer the question in the title - the Bleak Falls Barrow quest has no bearing on your ability to get a house in Falkreath.  If you are already Thane, the steward should offer you the land, however after reading both [Elder Scrolls Wiki](http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/Lakeview_Manor) and [UESP](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Lakeview_Manor) it's not completely clear whether this requires that you are level 9 or not.  They both mention that you may receive a letter after you become thane and are level 9 informing you that the land is available.

As mentioned, the house in Falkreath is added by Hearthfire, so you need to have that installed to get the quest to buy land.

Answer (score 0):

When you become thane ‚ the Jarl give you a quest ( in Miscellaneous)‚ ans you have to help three people in Falkreath before beeing able to purchase a house.

Answer (score 0):

You reach level 8 and you will get a letter from the jarl about coming to see him. When you go to see him he will offer to make you a than, you can only become thane and buy a house by helping three people in the jarls city